# How to align equal sign and text after it

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignment

I want to write this text aligned

```
c = the center of circle
b = the board around each circle 
  = c+b+sin(x)
```

How can I do that?
I used  alignment but it didn't work can you provide simple example?
I have tried :

```
\begin{align*}
&c  &= &\text{the center of circle}\\
&b  &= &\text{the board around each circle }\\
&   &= &c+b+\sin(x)
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
c & = \text{the center of circle}           \\
b & = \text{the board around each circle}   \\
  & = c + b + \sin(x)
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

is this what you looking for?

i compose it as math expression in `align*` environment from the package `amsmath`, which has in the first two line text on the right side. ampersands serve as anchors to which are rows aligned.

Comment: Why did you convert the correct `\sin(x)` from the OP's question to `sin(x)` without backslash?

Comment: @marmot, oh, typing error :-). thank you for pointing me to it. corrected now.